# Sign a PDF file to verify integrity and validity

Tags: pdf, gpg, signature

I've been asked to distribute electronic certificates (they were originally paper), in a PDF format, but I'd like to sign them with gpg or something similar so users can upload them to my site to check that they've not been handed a fake copy.

So, I'd like to sign a PDF file (transparently, the user doesn't need to know about anything) and check if its valid.

Comment: PDFs have their own signing system; you should ask about it on https://stackoverflow.com, you'll get an answer there.

Comment: Questions on this topic could be posted on [so] if you're asking how to write a program to do this, or here if you're asking for an existing program that does this. @StephenKitt This question is on-topic here, asking for existing programs.

Comment: @Liczyrzepa [su] is not “another stackoverflow site”, it's another Stack Exchange site. [so] is about programming, [su] is about computers (mainly PC running Windows but also some other systems). This question would also be on-topic on [su], but it's fine here on U&L. In any case, [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Gilles Right, I stand corrected ;-). I suggested SO because I know there are a few PDF experts there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with a separate signature file.

1. Sign the Document:

   `% gpg --output doc.pdf.sig --detach-sig doc.pdf`
2. Distribute `doc.pdf` and `doc.pdf.sig`
3. Verify the Document:

   `% gpg --verify doc.pdf.sig doc.pdf`

Comment: This is what I needed, although I won't distribute the .sig, I'll keep it to verify server-side